# D3.Js require a file with a dynamic string path

Tags: javascript, string, d3.js

I am building a visualization in D3.js and I have been importing the data like this:

```
[1] d3.json( "data/HoneyProduction-2013.json", function( honey_data ){...
```

In order to make it more user friendly and to make it easier for the user to analyze more data, I have implemented a slider.

From that slider, the user is going to select the year that he intends to analyze, and it will be displayed on a a specific heading that I have assigned the id `vardatayear`.

On my .js file, I have created a variable to get the element from that id

```
[2] var honeyyear = document.getElementById("vardatayear");
```

Now, my goal is to create a dynamic string in the file path in the import [1], that requires the var honeyyear (to define the year of the file) in order to pick up the file from that specific year.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a template string

```
d3.json( `data/HoneyProduction-${honeyyear}.json`, function( honey_data ){...
```

**Edit**

```
d3.json( `data/HoneyProduction-${honeyyear ? honeyyear : sliderInitVal}.json`, function( honey_data ){...
```

Comment: Thanks @riov8. I would just need to tweak the variable as I don't want it to be null assigning it a default value, similar to the year that I am starting the slider.

Comment: It is making a GET request to: `HoneyProduction-[object%20HTMLHeadingElement].json` instead of `HoneyProduction-2013].json`

Comment: This `var honeyyear = document.getElementById("vardatayear") || 2013;` and `var honeyyear = document.getElementById("vardatayear")

if(!honeyyear){
    honeyyear  = 2013
}` also didn't work

Comment: @GoncaloPeres: You have the DOM element, you need to get the `text` of the DOM element and convert it to a number: `+document.getElementById("vardatayear").text` or `.value`